# JS/JQuery Динамическое добавление HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dynamic

Мне нужно, чтобы при регистрации выводилось уведомление о успешной регистрации.
Моя первоначальная идея заключалась в том, чтобы объявить обычный html тэг и просто через css присвоить ему display:none; а потом при отправке формы менять его на block. Но я понял, что люди с базовым знанием, могут сами отобразить сообщение, а мне это не нужно.

Насколько корректен нынешний код? Есть ли другие варианты добавления динамического HTML? Просто этот вариант, не совсем удобен..

````
<script>
function normalert() {
                $('#suda').append('<h1 style="position: relative; left:40%;">Регистрация успешна!</h1>');
            }
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('form').submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    setTimeout("normalert();", 1000);
                })
            });
    </script>
    ```
````

Comment: "Но я понял, что люди с базовым знанием, могут сами отобразить сообщение, а мне это не нужно" --- что это значит?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский люди с базовыми знаниями вэб-разработки могут открыть иеспектор  и ткнуть display: block элементу, сообщение появится, а ему это не нужно )

Comment: @teran я хотел, чтобы он сам мне сказал))) чтобы я потом спросил "а что в этом страшного?" :)))

Comment: автор, люди с базовыми знаниями могут с таким же успехом просто руками вписать в нужное место этот ваш html-фрагмент. но да, код своеобразный.

Comment: То-есть в любом случае можно будет показать это сообщение? Даже если регистрация ещё не завершена? Думаю проверку написать

Comment: Показать сообщение можно будет *после*  отправки сообщения. Вы даже сами это писали